# CSS clip path shadow effect for polygon

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am developing my portfolio &  I want to add my technology skills to a visualization 3d hover effect like this - [3d objects of idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YDWL.png).

I am a beginner so my idea is simple. I'm gonna make small-sized cards of different shapes like circles, polygons, squares, triangles etc. Then I simply put images into those cards like - Java logo, react logo etc.

I have created the card part. [my card section where I'll create objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clc6m.png) But now I want to add some shadow effects to these small cards so that it look like 3d shapes & when I hover my mouse it should rotate 180 to Y axis & another card having same size & shape will appear from that back like a 3d effect having same technology logo but in a different style.

I have also tried using box-shadow property but it is not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Here is my JSX code -**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Highlights.css'
import image1 from '../../Images/java.png'
const Highlights = () => {
  return (
    <div className='highlight'>
      <div className='highlight-text'><h1>Highlights</h1></div>
      <div className="cards-img">
        <div className="pentagon-card">
          <img src={image1} alt="#" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Highlights
```

**Here is my css code-**

```
.highlight {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.cards-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: 205px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.pentagon-card {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(149, 230, 185), rgb(149, 230, 185));
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(223, 107, 12, 0.74);
}

.pentagon-card>img {
  transform: scale(0.7);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Give use your rendered HTML for your component. It's hard to debug without it. Also, I believe you're looking for [drop-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow)

Comment: @disinfor I am not sure what you are trying to say but I believe that I have attached my rendered component as a jpg file. You can look at that - ( my card section where I'll create objects )

Comment: No, we don't want an image of your component. Post the rendered **HTML** from the browser of your component. Right now, we don't have a way to test your code.